# Uma classe pode ser um tipo de dados?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, tipagem

O que eu entendo a respeito de *tipo de dados* é que eles são formados por três propriedades, elas são:

1. Conjunto de endereços;
2. Conjunto de Operações;
3. Espaço em Memória;

Assumindo o que esta a acima eu posso entender que uma classe que eu crio por exemplo classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa
{
   private string Nome {get; set;}

   public Pessoa()
   {
      this.Nome = "";
   }
}
```

Que esta classe `Pessoa` é um tipo de dados como **string**, **int**, **char** ou **double**? Ou uma classe não pode ser considerado um tipo de dados?

Comment: Não posso falar sobre os 3 itens citados, não parece ser uma definição correta, mas se der uma referência de onde isto é usado ou mais detalhes, posso tentar falar algo sobre isto.

Comment: É mais conceitual mesmo, os 3 itens citados foi o que entendi na faculdade, eu posso estar errado a respeito disso tambem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, uma classe é um tipo de dados. Em C# há uma definição clara sobre isso até mesmo na [sua especificação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). A classe é um dos tipos possíveis, os outros são, até o momento, as estruturas (`struct`), os delegados (`delegate`), que podem ser expressados com *lambdas*, as enumerações (`enum`), as interfaces (`interface`), e tuplas (ainda que pode haver contestação se é uma forma pura de criar um tipo).

A palavra **tipo** é usada genericamente para classificar todas essas formas de estruturas de dados das mais simples às mais complexas. Cada uma dessas formas diferentes de estruturas citadas tem características próprias, mas todas são declarações de como um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) deve ser formado.

Então `Pessoa` antes de ser uma classe, é um tipo. Tem linguagens que não possui sintaxe explícita própria para cada forma e chama tudo de `type`.

Se usar o operador `typeof` em `Pessoa` receberá um tipo ([`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), óbvio, né? Então é um tipo.

Comment: Rápido e ligeiro como sempre hehe

Comment: O que seria as **estruturas**? Uma struct neste caso?

Comment: É isso mesmo...