# Como uma máquina identifica o tipo de dado?

Tags: tipagem, independente-de-linguagem

Há pouco tempo me veio à cabeça uma dúvida de como uma máquina define/identifica o tipo de dado. Digo, quando estamos uma aplicação de alto nível nós temos as definições de que aquele dado pode ser um `integer`, `string`, etc. Porém, "por baixo dos panos" como ficaria?

Imagino que para cada linguagem há uma maneira distinta na estrutura dos dados e a quantidade de bits/bytes armazenados para cada tipo. Mas como isso é feito de uma maneira geral?

Comment: Acredito que não identifica, isso é só a linguagem mesmo que utiliza, no caso das compiladas, gerando um bytecode entendivel pelo niveis mais baixos.

Comment: Cada implementação de linguagem é livre para fazer como quiser. Uma possibilidade simples é o objeto manter um campo que seja uma referência à classe a partir da qual ele foi criado-- seja essa referência um endereço de memória ou um nome qualificado (p. ex.: com.meudominio.minhaaplicacao.meupacote.MinhaClasse ). No caso dos tipos primitivos, é suficiente verificar apenas durante a compilação, já que não há complicações como polimorfismo.

Comment: "[...] gerando um bytecode entendivel pelo niveis mais baixos." - Mesmo assim são níveis mais baixos da própria linguagem, você quis dizer, @diegofm?

Comment: Resumindo o que o foi dito aqui: Uma máquina só interpreta o seguinte: "Tem informações em uma região de memória que vai da região x à y"<br>
Ela não sabe mais que isso. A máquina (entendo que esteja falando de hardware) não sabe "oh, isso é um inteiro, isso é uma string". Em C você pode ver isso quando começa a brincar com ponteiros.

Comment: Exatamente isso que ,como eu mencionei, imaginava, @FelipeDiniz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A máquina não identifica nada. Tipagem é conceito abstrato existente em linguagens de alto nível. "Elas" escolhem os tipos e as regras para eles. Para o computador só existem um monte de bits, ele espera que existam alguns conjuntos deles formando bytes ou palavras (veja mais abaixo).

## Conceito de linguagem

Claro que ninguém vai inventar nada que não seja intuitivo, que fuja do padrão que crie dificuldades para a máquina manipular.

Em [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) a linguagem determina isso. [Quando alguém cria uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101) pensará nos tipos que podem ser considerados primitivos ou escalares, os derivados que formam um conjunto homogêneo ou heterogêneo de outros tipos e até se o usuário dela pode criar seus próprios tipos.

As [primeiras linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101) eram simples demais e nem precisavam se preocupar com isso. Problemas mais complexos e códigos maiores exigiram a tipagem.

O que existem são bits, o resto é abstração, ainda que esse termo é complicado de ser usado já que sempre há um nível de abstração, até o bit é uma delas.

## Tipos comuns

Os [tipos primitivos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) tentam aproveitar alguma vantagem do processador. Então é comum um inteiro ser do tamanho do registrador do processador, assim ele pode fazer uma computação de forma atômica e rápida. Ou seja, é comum ser uma [palavra (termo técnico)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

Alguns [processadores possuem instruções específicas para determinado formato de dados e seu funcionamento varia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101). Isso pode ajudar definir um tipo abstratamente. Essas instruções esperam algum formato específico. Você pode construir um dado bit a bit, mas no final para funcionar com essas instruções ele precisa estar no formato esperado, se não estiver o resultado não será o esperado e poderá até levantar alguma sinalização de problema em alguns casos, mas não na maioria.

Vou usar nomes de tipos comuns, mas que pode variar de linguagem para linguagem.

#### Integer

Ele é uma sequência de bits (o mais comum é 32) que pode ter um deles indicando o sinal e os demais o número em potência de 2. O normal é acharmos que os bits da direta sejam os menos significativos e os da esquerda são os mais significativos, como fazemos com números decimais. Isto realmente ocorrem em arquiteturas *big-endian*, como o ARM. Mas arquiteturas como Intel usam *little-endian*, o mais significativo vem por último, o que é contra intuitivo para nós, mas é vantajoso para o mecanismo. Isso é conhecido como [*endianess*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

[image: Little Endian][image: Big Endian]

Veja [detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).

## Float

Os processadores modernos possuem registradores especiais para certas operações, como [cálculo de ponto flutuante binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). Isso dá um bom tipo, mas mesmo quando isto não existe o tipo é útil porque a forma como os seus bits são dispostos tem características próprias.

[image: Floating Point]

Veja [detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

## Vector

Há também registradores e instruções especiais para vetorização de dados. Poucas aplicações fazem uso disto e era comum as linguagem não fornecem suporte direto nelas, mas cada vez mais em bibliotecas ou otimizações de compilador.

Em tese a linguagem poderia não ter tipo algum e deixar tudo para biblioteca, mas pode haver perda de performance fazendo assim.

## Byte

O byte existe por ser a menor unidade possível de informação que se armazena diretamente na memória (8 bits). Muitas vezes é confundido com o [caractere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)), mas isso não é uma verdade absoluta há muito tempo.

## Bit

[Tipo booleano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) costuma ser um byte mesmo. Mas se tiver uma sequência deles pode tratar como bit e armazenar até 8 por byte.

## Short

Outros tipos inteiros são criados para gerar economia em memória e não ocupar bits além do necessário que o valor máximo que ele deva carregar.

## Long

Há tipos que precisam passar do tamanho do registrador, não é o ideal, mas há motivos semânticos para fazê-lo. Em alguns casos tipos maiores podem caber no registrador.

## Pointer

Um outro tipo comum é o ponteiro, afinal ter um endereçamento de onde está uma informação é uma das coisas mais importantes que existe. Ele não deixa de ser um inteiro, não tem nada de especial nele a não ser o que espera que ele faça.

Veja [detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)).

## Primitivos compostos

Muitos tipos são formados por alguns conjuntos de bits, onde cada um possui algum significado, carrega uma informação específica.

[Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), por exemplo [é só uma forma específica de usar um tipo inteiro ou um conjunto de inteiros, ou ainda com conjuntos de bits segurando cada informação, o formato específico varia.

[Tipo decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type) ou monetário é o mesmo. Esses são bem diferentes dos tipos de ponto flutuante e cada linguagem tem uma forma diferente de montá-los. Algumas possuem tipos decimais de tamanhos diferentes.

## Tipos compostos

Os tipos não escalares, chamados de compostos, são formados pelos tipos primitivos, seja em sequência ([*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) - [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type), por exemplo), seja em conjunto com outros tipos ([estrutura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137393/101), [classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113651/101), por exemplo) ou os [Abstract Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). Incluindo a [*string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)).

Cada linguagem ou biblioteca pode ter sua forma de manipular uma *string*, mas o básico é ter um ponteiro (endereço) e uma sequência de bytes (caracteres).

A linguagem e principalmente a biblioteca padrão vão criando tipos novos conforme a necessidade ou conveniência que deseja fornecer para o programador.

Daí você vai tendo coisas bem mais complexas como [`Stream`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)), [`HashTable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), `Window`, `Cliente` e qualquer outra [classe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)).

## Sistema de tipos

Em linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) costuma haver vários tipos para o dado, só que a variável não possui tipo fixo, então precisa de uma estrutura para controlar isso, afinal na memória, no registrador tem um formato específico de bits.

Em linguagens de tipagem forte uma sequência de bits só pode ser interpretada como um tipo, se quiser que seja outro tipo tem que converter, possivelmente gravando o resultado em outro lugar. Em linguagem de tipagem fraca, de acordo com a necessidade pode considerar aqueles bits como uma coisa ou outro. Em algumas linguagens é comum fazer um ponteiro ser lido como se fosse um inteiro, só para ficar no exemplo básico.

Há linguagens monotipo ou até mesmo sem tipo - acessa tudo de forma bruta. Claro que não faz sucesso.

## Complemento

Tem uma [pergunta no SO específica para o Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13422259/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendido, bigown. Apesar de haver uma "regra" básica para definição dos tipos, cada linguagem ficará a cargo de como será feita essa definição. Correto?

Comment: Sim, ela pode, mas na prática isso não ocorre com os tipos mais básicos.