# Em programação, o que é um objeto?

Tags: terminologia, objetos

Em programação, é comum ouvir o termo `objeto`, muitas vezes, definido em múltiplas definições vagas, se definido.

O que é, de fato, um objeto em programação (não se limitando à programação orientada a objetos)?

Comment: Tem algum contexto?

Comment: @bigown Na declaração de variáveis, tenho alguns professores que não se referenciam à variável como "variável", e sim objeto. Mas, por exemplo, uma variável do tipo inteiro, é um objeto? Fiquei um pouco confuso com tanto professor falando de formas diferentes, então vim buscar uma definição mais concreta do que é objeto.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88546/significado-da-terminologia-orientado-a-objeto)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença entre Objeto e Instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192233/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença em instanciar, inicializar e declarar uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/5878)

Comment: Na verdade o termo é usado em outro contexto naquela pergunta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100812/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-uma-classe-e-um-objeto)

Comment: Novamente, a verdade o termo é usado em outro contexto naquela pergunta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Um objeto físico é uma porção de átomos. É algo físico (dããã). Claro que em programação lidamos com abstrações. O que seriam os átomos para nós desenvolvedores? O bit, certo? A menor informação que o computador entende e é indivisível.

Então um conjunto de bits acaba formando um objeto se eles forem dispostos em um conjunto de quantidade e ordem específicas. Em tese um objeto poderia até ser um bit, mas na prática pra formar um objeto útil de fato precisamos de pelo menos 1 byte, possivelmente um conjunto deles, até muitos deles, que forme algo que possamos identificar especificamente. Obviamente que objetos, como sua contrapartida física, podem ser formados por um conjunto de outros objetos.

O objeto aí é o dado, a informação. Não importa o que ou onde está. Instruções são dados, então pode até ser uma instrução, um código. Pode ser um valor inteiro, um caractere, um texto, um *array*, uma estrutura de dados qualquer, pode ser o que compõe um dicionário, ou um cliente na memória, em arquivo, no banco de dados.

Uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) em programação é um nome que damos a um valor, ou podemos dizer que é um nome que damos a um objeto. Para facilitar é comum tratarmos a variável como se ela fosse o objeto. De uma certa forma a variável é um objeto também, mas é outro objeto, é uma caixa que contém o objeto que realmente importa (é só um local de armazenamento).

Estritamente falando o que foi dito pelo professor está errado, mas é plenamente aceitável fazer essa simplificação de dizer que a variável é o objeto, todo mundo faz isso. É comum usarmos quase sinônimos para enriquecer a linguagem e simplificar a comunicação. Objetos possuem identidade. Uma variável não.

Note que existem objetos que a única informação é um ponteiro para onde está outro objeto que é o que interessa mesmo para aquela variável. São os objetos por referência. Se há o ponteiro em um lugar e o valor que interessa em outro, são dois objetos.

Objeto nesse contexto é usado para algo genérico. [Na matemática vemos isso ocorrer de forma semelhante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object).

A orientação a objeto é colocar o objeto como centro do desenvolvimento. Algumas pessoas acham que o termo só é usado nesse paradigma. Em OOP o termo tem definições um pouco mais específicas, mas é o mesmo objeto de outras linguagens, só muda a organização geral do código que o gera e manipula.

Na pergunta [Por que usar ponteiros como parâmetros de funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205587/101) eu uso o termo objeto o tempo todo em uma linguagem que não é orientada a objeto. Todos usam esse termo em C o tempo todo.

Em outros contextos o termo pode ser algo totalmente diferente.

> uma variável do tipo inteiro, é um objeto?

O inteiro é um objeto. De certa forma a variável não deixa de ser um objeto secundário, ela é onde está armazenado esse inteiro, mas o que importa é o inteiro. Mas dizer que a variável é um objeto inteiro é bem aceito e é compreensível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Creio que a confusão do Vinicius se dá quando se leva em consideração os vícios de linguagem. Tipo, é comum por como antagônico objetos e primitivos. Essa antagonia faz sentido quando se leva em consideração o sentido reduzido contextualizado da palavra **objeto**.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso mesmo.

Comment: Me clareou bem sobre objeto. Apenas em uma parte que "acredito que entendi", mas, fica aquela dúvida de "entendi corretamente!?", em: "**Objetos possuem identidade. Uma variável não.**".

Comment: @rbz se não tem no site acho que cabe pergunta :) O que eu disse aí é só pra não achar que a variável é um objeto.

Answer (score 6):

Fazendo um adendo [à magnífica resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205491/41056).

Pelo contexto passado, creio que você está lidando com uma linguagem orientada a objeto com acesso a tipos primitivos, como Java e C#.

Um objeto em um mundo abstrato normalmente é definido como um conjunto de interações com o ambiente e, para saber como essas interações ocorrem, precisam ter estado interno. [Artigo sobre linguagens baseadas em objeto da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_languages?wprov=sfsi1) define um objeto como um conjunto de operações e estados. Nesse sentido, um tipo primitivo carrega consigo um valor, portanto é um objeto.

Em linguagens como Java, diz-se que algo é um objeto se ele é uma instância de uma classe (ou um *array*). Vide [especificação da linguagem Java, capítulo 4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1). Agora, devido à restrição do contexto do qual estamos lidando, um primitivo não pode ser um objeto, pois ele simplesmente é, não é uma instância de alguém.

Aproveitando e aprofundando um pouco para Java:

- interfaces são promessas de comportamento, por isso que elas só proveem métodos; linguagens com tipagem de pato não necessitam disso, porém linguagens checadas estaticamente podem tornar isso muito vantajoso;
- classes são uma coleção de comportamentos e atributos;
- classes podem usar uma outra classe para se definir, processo esse chamado de herança;
- uma classe pode implementar uma interface, assim ela promete que seus objetos tenham o comportamento prometido pela interface;
- uma classe pode delegar a implementação de um método para um próximo momento, como se ela prometesse um comportamento mas não o implementasse; essas classes são chamadas abstratas;
- uma classe não precisa ter nome, sendo ela uma classe anônima; essa situação é comum quando se precisa colocar um objeto que tenha um comportamento prometido em uma interface, porém o programador achou desnecessário criar uma classe só com isso;
- e, para confundir tudo, classes são objetos; e são objetos da classe `Class`.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada melhor na resposta e corrigi uns erros que eu nunca tinha visto você fazer :P (que eu faço muito :D) Não sei porque não falei antes, mas vai agora. Eu tenho mexido nas minhas respostas sobre primitivos para deixar mais claro sobre ele. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+primitivo. Uma das coisas que falo é que primitivo é uma simplificação do termo. Ele é um adjetivo, então o termo completo é **objeto primitivo**, o que reforça o que você comentou na minha resposta. Não gosto dessa ideia de linguagem orientada a objeto, isso não existe...

Comment: ...existe linguagem que permite e até incentiva isso. Objeto em qualquer linguagem pode ter comportamento, a diferença é que algumas forçam isso estar junto dele em alguns ou todos casos (ainda bem que nenhuma de sucesso exige que seja todos). Nas minhas respostas estou reforçando que esse coisa de Java falar que a definição deles que o que é objeto é que ferrou a cabeça das pessoas, é uma definição errada, e fala muito sobre a linguagem. Cito ela mesma pra mostrar como é ruim definir errado. Ela deu a ideia que primitivo é.

Comment: oposto a objeto, o que não é, e agora que eles terão objetos que nem são primitivos, nem são criados por classes, o que isso é então? Eles vão ter que fazer malabarismo ou fazer de conta que nunca falaram besteira e deixar pra lá.