# Por que usar ponteiros como parâmetros de funções?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, parâmetros

Eu já tenho um certo conhecimento sobre ponteiro, mas eu queria entender porque na maioria dos casos as pessoas utilizam ponteiros como parâmetros em funções.

Atualmente venho estudando algoritmos pelo portal Geeks for Geeks, achei ele muito bacana  porque tem os códigos como exemplo. Agora eu não entendo porque todo parâmetro de uma função as variáveis são tratadas como ponteiros e *arrays* também.

[Exemplo](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-swap-two-numbers/).

Comment: Tentei dar uma melhorada na sua pergunta, espero que não se importe

Comment: Ficou bem melhor sim. Obrigado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Materiais bons explicam o porquê em vez de ficar jogando exemplo pra pessoa se virar.

Dados são passados para funções por valor, então há cópia do seu valor do [argumento para o parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Isso pode ser o desejado ou não. Quando não é desejado o ponteiro serve de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para evitar a cópia do dado. Desta forma o que será copiado é só o ponteiro e não o valor que interessa. Isso tem duas vantagens.

Evitar a cópia é uma vantagem óbvia quando o dado é muito grande. Copiar 4 ou 8 bytes é bem mais rápido que copiar dezenas, centenas, milhares ou milhões de bytes.

Outro motivo é quando precisa que a alteração feita no parâmetro se reflita na variável do argumento, ou seja, quando terminar a execução da função tudo o que foi alterado naquele objeto deve ser preservado no objeto original passado para ela. Como está passando o endereço onde está o objeto, em qualquer lugar está referenciando o mesmo objeto, mexeu nele, todos lugares que o enxergam passam ver essa alteração já que não é uma cópia. Cópias produzem um novo objeto independente.

Essa é uma mudança semântica importante de como o valor é tratado.

[Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado colega, ficou bem claro agora... Como também aprendi umas coisas novas. Obrigado !!!