# Por que não precisa do `&` no `scanf();`?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

Aprendi que a variável sempre tem que ter `&`, mas nesse exemplo não precisa e mesmo assim mostra o resultado. Por que não precisou do `&` no `scanf();`?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)

{
  int int1, int2, int3;
  int *ptr_int = &int1;

 printf("Inteiro 1: ");
 scanf("%d", ptr_int);
 printf("Numero inserido: %d\n", int1);
 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sempre :) que você aprende que algo "sempre tem que ser" tem algo errado no aprendizado ou no mecanismo, porque se tem que colocar algo para obter um resultado, mas pode não colocar, é porque em alguma situação não precisa, caso contrário não deveria ser obrigado usar algo que tem que sempre usar assim em qualquer caso.

## Passagem de argumento por referência

Você tem que entender porque existe um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266756/101). E que ele é usado em um parâmetro de função como forma de torná-lo bidirecional, ou seja, ele faz com que você manda um valor para a função, mas se ele for alterado a variável que o continha na função chamadora terá seu valor alterado junto.

É isso que acontece no `scanf()`. Você está passando uma variável para a função não porque precisa mandar um valor para a função, de fato a variável pode nem ter um valor válido, para o `scanf()`isto não importa, a questão é que no final da execução do `scanf()` o valor digitado pelo usuário precisa ser colocado em algum lugar e ele coloca justamente na variável que você passou como segundo argumento (o primeiro é o texto de formatação, e pode haver outros argumentos com mais variáveis).

Então para que a variável na função chamadora receba o valor do `scanf()` ela precisa ser passada como uma referência, ou seja tem que ser um ponteiro para uma região da memória da variável (se ainda tem dúvida entenda o que é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)).

Você pode pensar: "mas por que não retorna esse valor?". Porque a função já tem um retorno para outra coisa, algo que as pessoas não percebem e quase sempre usam erradamente. Quase todo uso do `scanf()` deveria estar em um `if` para indicar se a operação foi bem sucedido, porque é isso que retorna. Você não deveria usar a variável que recebe o seu valor sem que seja feita uma verificação se deu tudo certo. [Leia a documentação e veja qual é o retorno do `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Veja mais em [Por que usar ponteiros como parâmetros de funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205587/101).

## Porque não precisa no exemplo

Então entenda que o mais comum quando se aprende usar o `scanf()` é fazer algo assim:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Isto é necessário porque você está passando o endereço da variável `x` para função `scanf()`, não está passando o valor de `x`. Para passar o endereço de memória uma operação é necessária, já que o padrão é que seja pego o valor da variável. [Esse operador é o `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101).

Mas tem alguns casos que não precisa. Por que? Porque a variável já é um ponteiro. Se o parâmetro de `scanf()` espera um ponteiro e sua variável já guarda um endereço de memória, não tem porque usar o `&`. Um caso bastante conhecido é:

```
char texto[11];
scanf("%s", texto);
```

`texto` já é um ponteiro, não precisa. Seu caso é a mesma coisa, `ptr_int` é um ponteiro, então não precisa usar nenhum operador para pegar endereço de memória, ele já é o que precisa, até porque ele já foi usado em (estritamente falando, de forma sem necessidade, só se faz isso em exercício didático):

```
int *ptr_int = &int1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ReferenceScanf.c).

Comment: Gostei da resposta, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 5):

A memória RAM (= random access memory) de qualquer computador é uma sequência de bytes.
A posição (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) que um byte ocupa na sequência é o endereço (= address) do byte.  (É como o endereço de uma casa em uma longa rua que tem casas de um lado só.)

Cada variável de um programa ocupa um certo número de bytes consecutivos na memória do computador. 
Uma variável do tipo char ocupa 1 byte.
Uma variável do tipo int ocupa 4 bytes e um double ocupa 8 bytes em muitos computadores.
O número exato de bytes de uma variável é dado pelo operador sizeof:  a expressão sizeof (int), por exemplo, dá o número de bytes de um int no seu computador.

Cada variável (em particular, cada registro e cada vetor) na memória tem um endereço. Na maioria dos computadores, o endereço de uma variável é o endereço do seu primeiro byte

**O endereço de uma variável é dado pelo operador  &**

**Por exemplo, o segundo argumento da função de biblioteca scanf é o endereço da variável que deve receber o valor lido do teclado**

> ptr_int já é um ponteiro para a variavel (é o endereço da variável
>   int1)

Por exemplo, se **int1** é uma variável e **ptr_int** vale **&int1** então dizer ***ptr_int** é o mesmo que dizer **int1**.

Comment: nossa muito obrigado maneiro e amadeu

Comment: de nada, bons estudos!