# Função com ponteiro?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

Enunciado:

> A nota de um estudante é calculada a partir de três notas atribuídas
> entre o intervalo de 0 ate 10, respectivamente, a um trabalho de
> laboratório, a uma avaliação bimestral e a um exame final. A media das
> três notas mencionadas anteriormente obedece aos passos: trabalho de
> laboratório: 2; avaliação semestral: 3; exame final: 5. De acordo com
> o resultado, mostre na tela se o aluno está reprovado (media entre 0 e
> 2,9), de recuperação (entre 3 e 4,9) ou se foi aprovado. Faca todas as
> verificações necessárias.

Eu tinha feito com uma função tipo float, que retornava a variável. Por questões de aprendizado resolvi tentar fazer com ponteiro, mas não deu muito certo.

Na parte da função que vai validar a nota

```
while (var < 0 || var > 10)
```

Se eu digito 5 por exemplo, ele da 0 e 1, mas não entendi bem o porquê então 0 ou 1 da 1, aí ele entra e fica em um *loop* pedindo para digitar uma nota valida. Por que acontece isso?

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

void validar(float *var){
    scanf("%f", var);

    while (var < 0 || var > 10){
        printf("\nNota invalida, tente novamente: ");
        scanf("%f", var);
    }
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    float lab, avaliacao, exame;

    printf("Entre com a nota do trabalho de laboratorio: ");
    validar(&lab);

    printf("Entre com a nota da avaliação bimestral: ");
    validar(&avaliacao);

    printf("Entre com a nota do exame final: ");
    validar(&exame);

    float media = (lab * 2 + avaliacao * 3 + exame * 5) / (2+3+5);

    printf((media < 3) ? "\nAluno reprovado.\n" : (media < 5) ? "\nAluno em recuperação\n" : "\nAluno aprovado\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (var < 0 || var > 10)
```

Neste caso quer validar `(*var)`, ao colocar `var` está a usar o endereço

A resposta correta seria `while ((*var) < 0 || (*var) > 10)`

Ao fazermos:

```
 printf("%d\n", var);
 printf("%f\n", *var);
```

OUTPUT com *var=10:

```
6356744
10,000000
```

Answer (score 6):

Quando vai aprender um conceito novo primeiro estude bastante o que é ele antes e começar fazer, assim consegue entender o que está acontecendo e aproveita bem mais. Só fazer funcionar não é exatamente o que eu chamaria de aprender.

Você passou a variável como um ponteiro. Entende que está passando um ponteiro para um endereço de memória onde está realmente o valor e não o valor?

Por isso no `scanf()` não precisa passar com o operador de endereço `&` (como exemplificado em [Por que não precisa do `&` no `scanf();`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321827/101)), sendo que é um endereço que ele espera, a variável `var` já é um endereço.

Em outros locais não espera um endereço, espera um valor, então pode usar a variável diretamente, tem que fazer uma operação que pegue o valor do endereço. Isto é chamado *dereference*. Usa-se o operador `*` para dizer ao compilador que quer o valor que está no endereço tal. Aí funciona. Note que apesar de ser o mesmo caractere, neste contexto ele não é nem a multiplicação, nem o indicador de tipo ser um ponteiro.

```
while (*var < 0 || *var > 10) {
    printf("\nNota invalida, tente novamente: ");
    scanf("%f", var);
}
```

Assim fica melhor, tem código menos redundante:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void validar(float *var){
    while (1) {
        scanf("%f", var);
        if (*var >= 0 && *var <= 10) return;
        printf("\nNota invalida, tente novamente: ");
    }
}

int main() {
    float lab, avaliacao, exame;
    printf("Entre com a nota do trabalho de laboratorio: ");
    validar(&lab);
    printf("Entre com a nota da avaliação bimestral: ");
    validar(&avaliacao);
    printf("Entre com a nota do exame final: ");
    validar(&exame);
    float media = (lab * 2 + avaliacao * 3 + exame * 5) / (2 + 3 + 5);
    printf((media < 3) ? "\nAluno reprovado.\n" : (media < 5) ? "\nAluno em recuperação\n" : "\nAluno aprovado\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7M0AQL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ecsfrxab-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Dereference.c).

Mas parabéns por ter melhorado no que já sabia, muitas perguntas aqui a gente vê a pessoa continuar errando nas mesmas coisas.