# Printf não mostra todas as variáveis

Tags: c, c++

Estou estudando C/C++ na faculdade e me deparei com o seguinte problema, quando executo o seguinte código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main(){

    char name[10];
    int faltas;
    double media;

    printf("Digite seu nome, quantidade de faltas e sua media: \n");
    scanf("%s" "%d" "%.2f", &name, &faltas, &media);
    printf("Ola %s, voce tem %d faltas e sua media e %.2f",name,faltas,media);
}
```

Só que o resultado não aparece o valor da média, como mostra a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o que posso estar fazendo de errado, pois no exercício dado pelo professor a resolução é a mesma do código que coloquei acima.

Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: O scanf não sabe (e não tem como resolver de forma simples) que você está usando "," para separar os decimais na média  - use o ponto decimal "." e deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William,

Seu scanf está incorreto, a leitura de double é feita com lf, você também abriu e fechou a string mais de um vez no primeiro parâmetro, a leitura de string (array de char com %s) não é enviada com & na frente, pois trata-se de um array.

---

Para corrigir, abra somente uma vez a string do primeiro parâmetro, no valor %.2f, substitua por lf, e ao enviar o name, não utilize o &, o resulto será o seguinte:

```
scanf("%s %d %lf", name, &faltas, &media);
```

---

> Sua função main está com o retorno void, isso até compila, mas deve estar gerando warning, pois normalmente a main retorna um inteiro, sendo int main(), você pode retornar 0 apenas como teste.

Comment: Com o requinte de crueldade que o `&` a mais no `name` na chamada de `scanf` faz o programa usar a variável que deveria conter o ponteiro para o endereço dos 10 bytes reservados para colocar a sequência de caracteres digitados. C é assim - um errinho desses e você só não toma um segfault por sorte, e ainda parece que o programa funciona (o nome é impresso, afinal, apesar de os dados estarem em uma área arbitrária da memória )

Comment: Olá Daniel, programa continua retornando o mesmo resultado, mostra nome, a quantidade de faltas, mas a media permanece zerada

Comment: William, isso não deveria ocorrer, você recompilou seu programa? Veja esse exemplo online https://repl.it/repls/GraveEveryOpensource ou esse aqui https://repl.it/repls/MotherlyVoluminousConditionals

Comment: Daniel, removi o executável anterior e compilei novamente, rodei e deu certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!!!

Comment: Show, quanto ao ponteiro do array, dá uma olhada nessa resposta do Maniero, bem legal: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321827/por-que-não-precisa-do-no-scanf

Comment: Pode deixar, vou dar uma olhada!

Answer (score 0):

Você usou os formatadores para float "%f" ao invés dos formatadores para double "lf", tanto no scanf quanto no printf. A sua leitura de string também está errada já que se trata de um array, eu usaria o comando gets pra ler essa string em específico, limpar o buffer e depois ler os outros dados do programa.

Comment: Bom dia, por se tratar de um exercício da faculdade, eu ainda não tinha visto a função citada por você, mas obrigado pela dica!!! Ps.: O professor tinha passado a resolução deste printf errado (Na forma que se encontra na minha pergunta).