# Como um ponteiro pode apontar para uma função?

Tags: c, c++, funções, ponteiro

Um ponteiro aponta para um endereço de memória, então como um ponteiro é capaz de apontar para uma função?

Se a resposta for "funções também tem endereços" então, por favor dê mais detalhes.

E se for possível responder, no C++, por exemplo, por que os ponteiros de funções são diferentes dos normais?

```cpp
// Ponteiro "normal"
void* p = &x;

// Ponteiro de funções
void(*p)() = f;
```

Comment: Uma função esta armazenada EM UM endereço de memória. O que muda para uma variável, por exemplo, é a forma que é acessada/usada. No caso de uma função, em asm x86 msvc é usado a instrução `CALL` para chamá-la (que tem umas pequenas diferenças do `JMP`).  Uma variável pode estar no endereço 0x00004 a função em 0x00008, vai mudar a forma como são usadas através de funções específicas do assembly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a função se transforma em um conjunto de instruções em código de máquina. 
Esse conjunto de instruções da função fica armazenado em um endereço de memoria, por isso, por exemplo, se consegue usar a mesma função muitas vezes no programa em "lugares" diferentes.

Quando se declara a função é a mesma coisa de estar se declarando uma variavel. Um endereço é atribuido para ela. E dentro desse endereço fica as instruções.

De modo grosseiro, é isso.

Comment: Não fica armazenado em um endereço de memória, fica armazenado na memória, que tem um endereço acessível, é o que eu escrevi na minha resposta, não a grosso modo.

Comment: Quando eu digo um "endereço de um lugar" eu estou me referindo exatamente "ao lugar".

Answer (score 7):

Uma função está onde? Na memória, certo? E toda a memória é endereçável, certo? Portanto a pergunta é por que uma função pode ser endereçada? Na verdade uma função sempre é endereçada, mesmo que você não veja o ponteiro para ela (muito comum a maioria das linguagens esconderem ponteiros), ainda assim quando chama uma função está na verdade desviando a execução do programa para o endereço apontado de acordo com o nome daquela função. A única forma de acessar uma função é pelo seu ponteiro. O que você está vendo aí nesse código é apenas uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) **extra** criada para personalizar a chamada.

Se você acha que uma função não tem endereço é porque acha que não está na memória e se não está lá, está onde então? Ou acha que tem alguma parte da memória que não é endereçável, aí a pergunta seria por que acha isso? Não crie exceções ao conceito onde não precisa.

Ponteiros de funções não são diferentes dos "normais" porque eles são normais, eles apenas apontam para uma função e se é para usar assim é preciso de uma sintaxe que indica que é um ponteiro para uma função, que indique ao compilador que aquela variável poderá ser chamada e aí ele permitir essa chamada quando for feita porque ele sabe que não é um simples dado.

Ponteiro é o mecanismo e isto não muda. O tipo de informação que o ponteiro aponta muda, aí a tipagem indica algo diferente e este é um caso que exige uma exceção na sintaxe.

Se quer saber porque não usa o operador `&` para pegar o endereço da função é justamente porque ele já é um endereço ([é a mesma questão dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321827/101)), então não tem que fazer nenhuma operação para pegar o endereço, ao contrário de um dado que você deve criar um ponteiro para poder usar, se ele ainda não é um endereço.

Embora funcione, não se usa esse tipo de código em C++, tem maneiras melhores, mais robustas e mais legíveis de fazer isto em C++, então está mostrando no código como se faz em C, ainda que compile com C++, mas esta é outra questão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma função quando se transformar em código de máquina é um conjunto de instruções, então aonde exatamente fica o endereço da função?

Comment: O endereço fica onde estiver o ponteiro, que você está usando no seu código ou onde o compilador colocar. Alguma coisa me diz que quer saber algo em específico, talvez já saiba ou pensa que sabe, mas isto não está na pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

A sua dúvida é em como está estruturada a memória de um programa. Pesquise por artigos sobre a **organização da memória de um processo** para ter uma visão mais ampla. Aqui vou dar apenas as noções mais básicas que te ajudarão a visualizar o que acontece na máquina.

Quando você manda executar um programa, o SO aloca um bloco na memória para armazenar as informações do novo processo. Entre essas informações está o **código do programa** (instruções, variáveis, funções etc) já vinculado com as *libs* estáticas. Não é possível saber o endereço exato de onde está o processo e isso pode ficar mudando constantemente caso tenham mais processos rodando que memória disponível para todos eles.

Porém, dentro do espaço alocado para o processo, **as instruções geralmente ficam nos menores endereços** do bloco. Em seguida, vem o bloco das variáveis estáticas e globais e acima temos o HEAP que cresce a medida em que seu programa aloca dados **dinamicamente**. No final do bloco do processo (maiores endereços) está o STACK que **cresce para endereços menores** a medida que suas funções vão sendo chamadas.

Execute [este código](http://cpp.sh/2j3d3) e observe a saída. Por questões de segurança, o compilador não nos deixa manipular/observar o endereço das funções, só podemos dizer a ele que queremos que tal ponteiro aponte para tal função.

Quanto a sintaxe, bem... uma função requer uma lista de parâmetros, já um objeto não. Logo, as sintaxes tem de ser diferentes. Os parênteses em volta do nome são para desambiguar da declaração de função. O motivo de não usar o operador `&` é o mesmo do array. O nome de uma função já é um nome de um ponteiro. Porém, isso é opcional, você pode usar o operador se quiser.

```
void *pnome = &x;
void (*pnome) (<parâmetros>) = [&]f;
void *pnome(<parâmetros>) = [&]f; // ERRO: função inicializada como objeto
```

Contudo, como o @Maniero já disse, essa sintaxe é herança do C. Em C++ existem formas melhores de trabalhar com ponteiros para função usando a [`std::function`](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).