# No dev c ++ esta dando um erro: id returned 1exit status

Tags: dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>  //biblioteca => Standard I/O

void tela1(){
    printf("*** FACEAR - EXEMPLO *** \n\n"); // Impressão na tela 
}

void TelaAjuda(){
    printf("*** COMPILACAO E EXECUCAO     *** \n" );
}
main()
{
    systen("cls");
    //Comentários no código
    tela();
    telaAjuda();    


    // Criação de variaveis 
    int a;
    int b;
    int s;

    // Inicialização com Zero
    a = b = s = 0;

    // Atribuição de valores
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    s = a + b;



    // Impressão na tela 
    printf("O valor da variavel a , b \n");
    printf("Soma de a e b %i \n", s);

    //Solicitar um valor
    printf("Digite um valor: ");    
    scanf("%i", a);

    printf("Digitado %i \n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17718171/10301489) da pergunta: [C compile error: Id returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717946/c-compile-error-id-returned-1-exit-status), em inglês:

Traduzida, via google translate:

> Eu posso supor, que a antiga instância do seu programa ainda está sendo executada. O Windows não permite alterar os arquivos atualmente "em uso" e o vinculador não pode gravar o novo .exe na parte superior do arquivo em execução. Tente parar / matar seu programa.

Acredito que isto resolverá a execução do seu código.

1) entretanto há uma série de pequenos erros no seu código, veja:

```
...
main()
{
    systen("cls");
    //Comentários no código
...
```

A forma correta de escrever a função é `system("cls");` e para utiliza você deve incluir a diretiva: `#include <cstdlib`>

2) Observe este trecho do seu código ao chamar as funções:

```
 ...
            tela();
            telaAjuda();  
        ...
```

Por sua vez, observe a implementação das suas funções:

```
...
void tela1(){
    printf("*** FACEAR - EXEMPLO *** \n\n"); // Impressão na tela 
}

void TelaAjuda(){
    printf("*** COMPILACAO E EXECUCAO     *** \n" );
}
...
```

**Seus nomes estão diferentes!**

1. `tela` **é diferente** de `tela1`;
2. `TelaAjuda` **é diferente** de `telaAjuda`

Lembre-se de que C++ É [Case-sensitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive)

3) O último erro,  você talvez perceba o aviso:

> warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

neste trecho:

```
 //Solicitar um valor
    printf("Digite um valor: ");    
    scanf("%i", a);
```

O correto seria:

```
scanf("%i", &a);
```

Porque o `scanf` necessita o endereço da variável `a`.

Para sanar mais dúvidas sobre scanf leia esta resposta: [Por que não precisa do `&` no `scanf();`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321831/110782)