# O resultado sai outro

Tags: c, algoritmo

Tenho tentado resolver este exercício que peguei na internet. Mas ele nunca sai o valor que eu quero. Qual o motivo?

> */*
>       João Papo-de-Pescador, homem de bem, comprou um microcomputador 
>       para controlar o rendimento diário de seu trabalho. Toda vez que 
>       ele traz um peso de peixes maior que o estabelecido pelo regulamento
>       de pesca do estado de São Paulo (50 quilos) deve pagar uma multa de
>       R$ 4,00 por quilo excedente. João precisa que você faça um programa 
>       que leia a variável peso (peso de peixes) e calcule o excesso. 
>       Gravar na variável excesso a quantidade de quilos além do limite e na variável 
>       multa o valor da multa que João deverá pagar. Imprima os dados do programa com 
>       as mensagens adequadas. 
>   */*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){   

   //variaveis
        float peso = 0, excesso = 0; 

        // Recebe o peso
        printf("Digite quantos quilos você coletou:\n");
        scanf("%d", peso);
        printf("=================================================\n");
        // Recebe o excesso
        printf("Digite quantos quilos de excesso foram coletados:\n");
        scanf("%d", excesso);
        printf("=================================================\n");

        //Calcular
        float calculo = peso + excesso;

        if(calculo >= 50){
            float multa = calculo * 4;
            printf("Você coletou: %d Kg.\n", calculo);
            printf("A multa a ser paga, será de: R$%d\n", multa);
        }else{
            printf("Você coletou: %d Kg.\n", calculo);
            printf("Não será necessário pagar multa!\n");
        }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Tem inúmeros problemas nesse código. Alguns são mais cosméticos ou não tão importantes, mas não é assim que se programa em C. Se aprende errado vai fazer sempre errado.

Os comentários são óbvios por isso eles não ajudam no entendimento do código, só poluem, por isso eu tirei.

A inicialização das variáveis não era necessária porque nunca usa esses valores antes de mudá-los, há uma perda de tempo inicializando sem uso. Não é importante para um exercício, mas acaba acostumando fazer errado.

A formatação para usar o tipo `float` nas funções de entrada e saída deve ser `f` e não `d` como usou.

Para passar uma variáveis para o `scanf()` deve ser através de uma referência sempre, como as variáveis ali não são referências, deve explicitamente passar como uma através do operador `&`.

O `if` tinha algo que é executado igual nos dois casos, então ele pode ficar fora do bloco e fica mais canônico e simples.

Mudei um nome de variável para ficar mais semântico e legível, isso é mais importante que comentários.

Além disso tem um problema de lógica. Você deve verificar se o peso é maior que 450 (não maior ou igual), e aí calcular a multa nesse caso. A multa deve ser calculada só sobre o excesso (não deve pedir qual é o excesso) que é o peso menos 50 kilos.

Estritamente o enunciado pede para "gravar" em variável os valores. Você optou por mostrar, não faz sentido fazer as duas coisas sem necessidade. Eu acho que mostrar é muito mais importante que colocar em variáveis, acho o enunciado ruim.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){   
    float peso; 
    printf("Digite quantos quilos você coletou:\n");
    scanf("%f", &peso);
    printf("=================================================\n");
    printf("Você coletou: %f Kg.\n", peso);
    if (peso > 50) printf("A multa a ser paga, será de: R$%f\n", (peso - 50) * 4.0);
    else printf("Não será necessário pagar multa!\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I7ezhH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xzlqszsm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PriceOver.c).

Se quiser por em variáveis:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){   
    float peso; 
    printf("Digite quantos quilos você coletou:\n");
    scanf("%f", &peso);
    printf("=================================================\n");
    printf("Você coletou: %f Kg.\n", peso);
    if (peso > 50) {
        float excesso = peso - 50;
        float multa = excesso * 4.0;
        printf("A multa a ser paga, será de: R$%f\n", multa);
    } else printf("Não será necessário pagar multa!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, você não esta imprimindo os valores corretos, pois não está passando o valor corretamente com a função scanf(), leia esta pergunta:[Por que não precisa do `&` no `scanf();`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321827/por-que-n%C3%A3o-precisa-do-no-scanf)

Posteriormente, na verdade, você interpretou a questão de maneira incorreta.  Pois seu código está 'pegando' o valor inteiro do peixe e multiplicando por 4( valor que será pago caso exceda os 50 kg). Para estar conforme o enunciado do exercício ele deve pegar **somente o valor em excesso e multiplicar por 4**.

Fiz algumas modificações em seu código:

1) Já que o excesso somente irá ser usado após 50 kg, atribui o 50 diretamente a variável( Você facilmente poderá mudar isto no futuro)

2) Arrumei a precisão do seu especificadores de formato  %f para duas casas decimais %.2f

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){   

   //variaveis
        float peso = 0, limite = 50; 

        // Recebe o peso
        printf("Digite quantos quilos você coletou:\n");
        scanf("%f", &peso);
        printf("=================================================\n");
        // Recebe o excesso


        //Calcular
        float calculo = peso - limite;

        if(peso > 50){
            float multa = calculo * 4;
            printf("Você coletou: %.2f Kg.\n", calculo);
            printf("A multa a ser paga, será de: R$%.2f\n", multa);
        }else{
            printf("Você coletou excedeu os quilos\n");
            printf("Não será necessário pagar multa!\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse variável calculo não é necessária, pois a condição para calcular o excesso é quando o peso ultrapassar os 50 kg.

```
    float peso, multa; 

    printf("Digite quantos quilos voce coletou: \n");
    scanf("%f",&peso);

    multa = 0;

    if(peso >= 50){
        multa = peso * 4;

        printf("Voce coletou: %.2f Kg \n", peso);
        printf("A multa a ser paga, sera de: R$%.2f\n", multa);
    }else{
        printf("Você coletou: %.2f Kg.\n", peso);
        printf("Não será necessário pagar multa!\n");
    }
```