# Parâmetros com vetores em Java são sempre por referência?

Tags: java, array, método, parâmetros, referência

Tenho ciência de que, em Java, qualquer passagem de parâmetro de um objeto é por referência, já com tipos primitivos, por valor. No entanto, fiquei com dúvida quanto ao vetor comum. Não me refiro a classe `Vector`, e sim a um simples vetor do tipo:

```
 Tipo vetor = new Tipo[Tamanho]
```

Ao passar um vetor assim como parâmetro em um método estarei alterando o próprio vetor ou gerando uma cópia? Um vetor é considerado primitivo ou objeto (uma vez que ele aponta para o endereço do primeiro elemento)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ao passar um vetor assim como parâmetro em um método estarei
>   alterando o próprio vetor ou gerando uma cópia?

Vai alterar o próprio array. O método recebe como parâmetro o endereço do array na memória, logo você pode alterar o valores do array referenciado, mas não sua referência.

> Um vetor é considerado primitivo ou objeto?

É um objeto. Em Java há classes para cada tipo de array. Essas classes estão fora do escopo do programador.

```
Array type             Corresponding class Name
int[]                     [I
int[][]                   [[I
double[]                  [D
double[][]                [[D
short[]                   [S
byte[]                    [B
boolean[]                 [Z
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-primitive-type-object-java/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062177/5360385

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Vi a referência que colocou e este artigo sobre Arrays e tipo primitivo ajudou na compreensão, apesar de ser em inglês rs.

Answer (score 6):

> Tenho ciência de que, em Java, qualquer passagem de parâmetro de um objeto é por referência

Sua ciência está equivocada, apenas objetos originários de classes são passados por referência. Objetos vindos de outras formas também são [objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). No momento apenas os tipos originários de classes descendem de `Object` e por isso talvez algumas pessoas confundam o que é um objeto. Java cometeu o erro conceitual (e este é um dos motivos que a linguagem é criticada) de não tratar os tipos primitivos como tipos derivados de `Object`, desde então a linguagem teve que criar um monte de gambiarra para consertar os problemas causados por essa decisão ruim. Eu sempre falo: conceitue certo e seu software sobreviverá bem por muito tempo, não são metodologias (Agile), ou princípios (SOLID), ou paradigmas (OOP), ou abordagens (DDD), ou padrões de projeto ou arquitetura (MVC), muito piores práticas que fazem tudo dar certo, é sempre o conceito certo.

> já com tipos primitivos, por valor

Sim, isto é verdade, mas em breve terão novos tipos que serão passados por valor e provavelmente, desta vez, eles serão herdados de `Object`.

> No entanto, fiquei com dúvida quanto ao vetor comum. Não me refiro a classe Vector, e sim a um simples vetor do tipo: `Tipo vetor = new Tipo[Tamanho]`. Ao passar um vetor assim como parâmetro em um método estarei alterando o próprio vetor ou gerando uma cópia?

Internamente um *array* é como uma classe, é um tipo por referência como outro qualquer. Todos os objetos grandes precisam ser usados por referência para serem eficientes. Novamente, ele foi conceituado errado e por isso tem algumas dificuldades, mas funciona.

Haverá alteração dos valores internos dentro dele como outros tipos por referência, alterou dentro de um método essa alteração se refletirá na variável que foi usada para sustentar esse objeto.

> Um vetor é considerado primitivo ou objeto?

Ele é as duas coisas. É um tipo primitivo (que é diferente de ser por valor) e ele é um objeto, que são todos os tipos (estes são os conceitos corretos). Além disto ele é um tipo por referência, conforme eu informei antes não há a relação que está achando que há (a maioria das pessoas que programam em Java entendem errado, e com a evolução já preparada da linguagem isso ficará mais claro e vai explodir a cabeça de muita gente que aprendeu errado). No fundo isto se chama objeto primitivo, afinal "primitivo" é um adjetivo de algum substantivo, neste caso do substantivo oculto objeto.

Algumas pessoas podem considerar que um primitivo é só um valor típico que o computador lida diretamente, por essa definição ele não é um primitivo, mas dá questionar isso. Mas muitos consideram que primitivos é o que está definido pela linguagem e não pela biblioteca. [A wikipedia aceita as duas definições](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) (o que não quer dizer que seja uma informação canônica correta, eu gosto mais da definição que é algo *builtin* da linguagem), mas entendendo a definição tire suas conclusões (acho que pode considerar um *array* como algo que a máquina entende também, embora de uma forma menos direta, afinal ele é só  um ponteiro para um dado). Não sei como Java considerará, provavelmente saberemos isto quando ela implementar os tipos por valor definidos pelo programador, ela terá que definir melhor o que são as coisas.

> uma vez que ele aponta para o endereço do primeiro elemento

Isto não é verdade, isto vale para C, não para Java.

Em geral deve-se evitar o uso direto do *array* e usar classes mais abstratas como o `ArrayList` por exemplo que faz tudo o que o *array* bruto faz com vantagens. Mas há casos pra seu uso, inclusive por causa do legado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Foi muito boa. No entanto, acabei ficando com dúvidas em alguns pontos por tantas informações rs. Por exemplo, quando distinguiu objetos, falando dos originários de classes pensei... "E existe objeto sem ter vindo de uma classe? rs"
Pesquisando o post que colocou como link, me parece que o termo objeto pode ser usado em outro contexto que não a OOP, no sentido de ser um dado... No entanto, só ouvi este termo em Orientação a Objeto e, por isto, ficou meio confuso.

Comment: Pelo menos a resposta está certa e poderia te ajudar aprender certo, várias pessoas consideraram assim. O que você acabou de dizer é  "eu aprendi errado e vou continuar assim porque o que importa é o que aprendi primeiro e não o certo". Mas se deseja é um direito seu, é uma pena, a oportunidade você teve.