# Quando usar record ou class no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, .net-5, record-types

Uma das novidades do C# 9 são os *record types*, vi que uma das maiores diferenças entre eles e as classes são os métodos `.ToString()` e `.Equals()` que tem um comportamento diferente. Porém quero saber se eu deveria levar em consideração outros pontos além desses métodos quando for escolher entre usar um ou outro, ou fazer essa comparação entre eles não está correta?

Resumindo: Quando eu deveria escolher entre usar `class` ou `record`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TL; DR

O maior motivo para adotar esse mecanismo é ter uma estrutura de dados simples que não adota o estilo comum em orientação a objeto, ou seja, há uma preferência pelo estilo funcional.

O `record` usado na forma como ele foi pensando é um tipo com semântica de valor mas que é armazenado como referência e tem tempo de vida descolado de quem o criou. Por isso ele é um substituto de uma `struct` e não uma exatamente da classe.

Falando como mecanismo, `record`, para todos efeitos, é uma classe, por isso acredito que haja essa confusão. Há uma pequena mudança e com isso uma motivação diferente. Esse mecanismo não tem limitações em relação ao que a classe pode fazer, ela tem, opcionalmente, algo a mais. Já o conceito é bem diferente.

## Mito da imutabilidade

No final cito a documentação oficial como fonte para mostrar o que é o mecanismo e como ele funciona. Mas na descrição do que é novo na linguagem ela está claramente errada em pelo menos um ponto, o que mina a credibilidade do resto.

> C# 9.0 introduces record types, which are a reference type that provides synthesized methods to provide value semantics for equality. Records are immutable by default.

[Fonte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Records não são imutáveis por padrão, pelo menos não diferente de como é a classe. Um campo é mutável por padrão em um `record`, se não quer que ele mude, tem que dizer que é `readonly`. Todos exemplos usam propriedades, e aqui até podemos considerar que elas são imutáveis por padrão porque só se você colocar um método `set` nela é que ela passa ser mutável de fato. Ok, mas isso é igual à classe.

É fato que `record` foi criado para facilitar o uso de estruturas imutáveis, mas não precisa ser assim. Nada de diferente tem nele que obriga ser imutável. E classe consegue fazer exatamente igual.

Agora existe um jeito novo para manipular a propriedade que é o `init`. Mas isso não é um recurso do `record`, é algo novo que funciona com a classe também. Este é um mecanismo que incentiva a imutabilidade, pelo menos pública, já que ele deixa colocar um valor inicial, mas não mais mexer no valor após isso.

Nada impede que o campo seja mudado internamente de forma diferente. Para ser totalmente imutável ainda deve fazer o campo ser `readonly`. E o `init` funciona bem com isso, na classe ou no registro.

Existe sim uma situação que o `record` é imutável por padrão:

```
public record Pessoa(string Nome, int Idade);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/RecordBasic.cs).

Na forma muito simples de sintaxe do `record` esse comportamento foi adotado, então só pode mexer no valor durante a inicialização do objeto, e como vemos não tem outras partes que mexem internamente. Na prática ele cria uma propriedade para você com o `init`.

Nessa forma não é que a imutabilidade é o padrão, é a única forma possível, pelo menos nos membros descritos nessa sintaxe chamada *primary constructor*, nada impede ter outros campos ou propriedades e elas serem mutáveis, o que fará a estrutura como um todo mutável.

Note que a imutabilidade é rasa, ou seja, só no objeto básico de cada propriedade, os objetos que compõem esse objeto não passam ser imutáveis automaticamente, é problema deles cuidar disso se for o caso. Não mudou em relação ao que já acontecia com a classe.

#### Construtor

Que fique claro, suporte a objetos imutáveis já ocorria com as classes. Houve uma simplificação da maneira de fazer isso e uma dessas simplificações é não precisar mais criar um construtor para fazer a inicialização, mas essa é uma *feature*  do `init` e não do `record`.

Tenho medo das pessoas começarem ignorar construtor, que pode sim ser ignorado em alguns casos quando tem o `init`, mas nem sempre deveria. Veja mais em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Quando o que deseja é o objeto ser imutável, o `record` pode ser uma preferência, mas não é só isso e esse questão é colateral.

## Reais motivo para usar um `record`

A simplificação é um motivo um pouco mais forte, mas ainda não o mais forte de todos para usar o `record`.

Tipos com **semântica de valor** tendem ser imutáveis, é verdade, mas não é obrigado que sejam.

Quando você queria semântica por valor podia usar classes, o maior exemplo é a `string`. Então o `record` não deu nada novo para a linguagem.

Tipos com semântica por valor e principalmente imutáveis já podiam ser adotados com `struct` e de forma mais clara e garantida com `readonly struct`.

O `record` deveria ser comparado com uma estrutura simples, porque é isso que ele é. Não deveria compará-lo com uma classe. Quando precisa de uma classe, use uma classe.

O maior motivo para adotar uma `struct`, e o mesmo vale para o `record` é ter uma estrutura de dados simples. Essas formas de composição de tipos tem como centro o uso de **dados** e não de um **objeto** complexo.

Leia [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101). E esqueça um pouco isso. Aqui estou usando o termo objeto pela definição da orientação a objeto. Um objeto é um componente complexo onde você tem algo coeso e que você acessa comportamentos como se fosse uma coisa única. Dados necessários para tudo isso funcionar não são importantes para o programador, é tudo detalhe de implementação, o objeto é o que importa. Para tudo isso funcionar mutabilidade é ser importante e costuma-se ter vários métodos que manipulam esse objeto. Os comportamentos tendem ser bem diferentes entre os objetos.

Em uma `struct` **o foco é o dado**, por isso costuma-se dizer que o uso de tipos primitivos ou tipos simples definidos pelo usuário (programador) é uma violação da orientação a objeto. Que bom.

Uma `struct` é um dado simples, não uma composição complexa. O dado é o que te interessa, não um comportamento coeso em cima de algo complexo. Ela sempre tem semântica por valor e de fato ela costuma ser por valor, exceto se usar uma `ref struct`.

Um `record` serve para a mesma coisa, ser uma estrutura com foco nos dados, com semântica por valor, provavelmente de forma imutável. Não à toa que inicialmente ele iria se chamar `data class`, ou seja, seria uma classe de dados, e não uma classe de um objeto, que é o normal.

Então por que usar um `record` no lugar de uma `struct` se ambos servem para o mesmo propósito?

Quando você precisa de tudo isso já descrito mas precisa **desvincular o tempo de vida com o criador desse objeto de dados**, então o `record` é recomendado. Um `record` é sempre um tipo por referência, ainda que a semântica padrão seja por valor, e ele é armazenado sempre no *heap*, a não ser que isso mude um dia. Estando no *heap* o tempo de vida é controlado por ter uma referência para ele, mas não importa de onde ela venha. Ele não depende do método que criou esse objeto estar em execução, ou de um objeto que o adotou inicialmente em um campo de ainda existir, ele só depende de alguma referência para ele existir.

Então o mecanismo é uma classe. De fato tudo o que pode fazer com uma classe pode fazer com ele. E tudo oque faz com ele pode ser feito com uma classe, sempre pôde.

> Ok, entendi porque adotá-lo, mas então porque inventaram isso se já dava para fazer igual antes?

Para facilitar o uso com semântica de valor. E também para deixar mais claro que você tem um objeto de dados e não um objeto no sentido da orientação a objeto. Há tempos eu falo que C# quer se afastar um pouco da ideia de OOP (sem abandonar). Essa forma incentiva um uso mais funcional da linguagem (sem adotar por completo).

> E como ele dá mais facilidade?

Ele provê automaticamente métodos que costumam ser necessários em um objeto com semântica por valor, que é o que já acontece quando você cria uma `struct`, mas não acontece quando cria uma classe. Inclusive boa parte das classes que as pessoas criam estão erradas por estarem incompletas, ainda que funcionem porque você acaba nunca usando o que não está feito, ou "ajeita" a situação para contornar a falta do mecanismo feito corretamente. Por isso sempre posto:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Então entenda o `record` como um `ref struct` que fica no *heap* e é gerenciado pelo *garbage collector*. Se você não sabe, o `ref struct` só pode estar na *stack*, ele não pode fazer parte de um objeto no *heap* (a `struct` pode).

Essa é decisão que você tem que tomar.

> Então quando penso em criar uma classe nem preciso pensar se deveria ser um `record`?

Não exatamente. O problema é que as pessoas são viciadas em criar classes quando, em alguns casos, na verdade deveriam criar `struct`, ou `ref struct`. E até tinha um motivo para adotar uma classe quando o certo é criar uma forma de `struct`. Sem um mecanismo que permita o tempo de vida ser desvinculado com quem criou o objeto, especialmente `ref struct` só podendo usar dentro de métodos, a única solução que existia era a classe. Mas ela era errada, apesar de funcionar bem. Agora tem o mecanismo adequado. Esse é o motivo real para existir e adotar um `record`.

Apesar de possível é inadequado usar semântica de referência em um `record` do C#.

## Mais informações sobre o `record`

[A Wikipedia dá uma definição bem razoável para o que é um *record*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)). Universalmente um registro não difere do que já conhece, é só um Plain Old Data com semântica de valor. Não há maiores detalhes sobre como eles devem ser implementados.

Para se ter uma ideia, o que chamamos de `struct` em C# é chamado de `record` em Pascal/Delphi. Algumas pessoas chamam a `struct` do C++ de *record*. Conceitualmente não compare ele com uma classe, apesar dele ser uma em C#, mas é detalhe de implementação.

A ideia de ser uma referência é algo que serviu bem à implementação do C# já que a linguagem já possuía um forma de registro totalmente por valor. Mas a semântica por valor é mantida para ainda ser um `record`.

O compilador do C# fornece implementações adequadas de alguna métodos que todos objetos possuem, entre eles o método de igualdade e operadores de comparação, o `GetHashCode()`, `ToString()` e formas de cópia e clone do objeto. Em algumas circunstâncias pode fornecer um [`Deconstruct()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/482769/101), os *getters e initializers* ou outros métodos também (como `PrintMembers()` e a implementação pode evoluir e ter outros). O construtor também é criado permitindo a inicialização dos dados. Portanto ele faz até um pouco mais que o compilador faz por uma [`ref`] `struct`. E ele sabe fazer do jeito certo, o programar nem sempre sabe. Isto é uma diferença importante para a classe.

O `record` não deixa de ser uma classe, então ele tem herança, por exemplo, e isso seria um bom motivo para adotá-lo quando precisa desse recurso da linguagem que não está disponível para uma [`ref`] `struct`. Só tome cuidado porque herança em tipos com semântica por valor podem ser um pouco complicados em alguns casos.

Importante dizer que esses métodos criados pelo compilador podem ser substituídos por uma versão sua se te atender melhor e souber o que está fazendo. E pode ter outros métodos adicionais, igual uma classe, só parece um pouco abuso. O `record` existe principalmente para atender demandas de [domínio anêmico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model).

Eu ainda não tenho opinião totalmente formada sobre o uso de um `record` como apenas uma classe imutável, para facilitar a concorrência por exemplo, até porque a classe serve a isso também. Porém eu acho que as pessoas usarão para isso por ser mais fácil que a classe e porque elas não conseguem criar os métodos corretos na classe. Muitas pessoas acreditarão que é só uma classe imutável até porque já tem muito material de segunda classe espalhado pela internet dizendo isso, os de primeira classe não cometem esse erro.

C# 10 tem `record` por valor (uma `struct` mesmo), então cada vez mais ele se torna uma opção interessante.

## Conclusão.

Use `record`s para:

- DTOs e domínios anêmicos
- Tipos simples, como uma `struct`, que precisam ter tempo de vida indeterminado
- Tipos com foco nos dados (não nos comportamentos), especialmente quando há relação entre eles mas não é um objeto único, de certa forma como se fosse uma tupla nomeada
- Classes imutáveis que serão usadas em contextos de concorrência e você saiba lidar com isso.

Um problema que eu vejo é que há incentivo nos exemplos em adotar classes que claramente são mutáveis como imutáveis. É o caso da *pessoa* que, por definição, muda seu estado ao longo da vida, além de ter vários comportamentos na maioria dos cenários, e por isso uma classe sempre foi muita adequada.

Em uma situação que precisa manter imutável para facilitar a concorrência um `record` pode ser adotado, porém quando precisa mudar um dado nesse objeto, outro é criado, porém é a mesma pessoa, você tem que lidar com isso. É o mesmo problema dos microsserviços, você começa ter inconsistências se não sincronizar os objetos que são diferentes com estados alterados mas que representam a mesma coisa, e é um problema mais difícil de resolver. Note que nem sempre isso é complicado, aí é ok usar.

Objetos imutáveis tendem ser menos eficientes em várias situações onde teria que fazer uma mutação obrigando a cópia, mas podem ser melhores em outras onde o domínio realmente é imutável. Não force algo ser imutável se ele não é ou se não usará em um ambiente que precisa ser concorrente.

Use onde ele te ajuda e não cria complicação.

Veja a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E [veja que F# já tinha um mecanismo igual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) porque sempre privilegiou o estilo funcional sobre o orientado a objeto. E [veja um bom tutorial de uso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/records?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 6):

A ideia do tipo `record` é dar suporte a entidades imutáveis, ou seja, um tipo de referência que irá manter seu valor por todo o contexto que está inserido.

Para utilizar uma classe imutável você tem de atender a uma série de pontos, como todas as propriedades apenas terem `getters`. No caso do `record` a ideia é ter tudo isso sem implementações de verificação.

Só que não. :(

Há uma [issue aberta no GitHub do .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/20601) exatamente falando que objetos do tipo `record` não apresentam erros de compilação quando sua propriedades são atribuidas após a construção. A solução de contorno é a utilização do também novo recurso de propriedades `Init-Only`.

Vamos supor o seguinte `record`:

```
public record Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Na essência do tipo, o código a seguir não compilaria:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.Nome = "Rogerson Nazario"; //Porém compila!
```

Para que haja o erro na linha do comentário anterior, o registro deveria ser como segue:

```
public record Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; init; }
    public int Idade { get; init; }
}
```

No [site oficial da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) há uma referência técnica sobre mais funcionalidades do `record`.