# Se strings em Python são imutáveis, como conseguimos alterá-la com o método replace()?

Tags: python, string, imutabilidade

Se strings em Python são imutáveis, como conseguimos alterá-la com o método `replace()`, por exemplo?

Ex:

```
s = "banana"

s = s.replace("b", "z")

print(s) # zanana
```

Isso é uma alteração da string original ou não? Eu estou atualizando o valor de `s` e não criando uma nova string. Não é isso?

Comment: Veja `id(s)` antes de depois do `replace` (Em CPython o `id` retorna o endereço de memória do seu objeto - se mudar, é porque criou um novo objeto).

Comment: Spoiler: se string fosse mutável, você não precisaria reatribuir `s` em `s = s.replace`, bastaria executar `s.replace` que mudaria internamente os caracteres, que não é o que acontece na prática. Listas, por exemplo, são mutáveis e você pode fazer o `append` sem ter que fazer algo como `lista = lista.append(...)`

Comment: `s` é uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e não um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) `string`. Com conceitos certos fica fácil entender.

Comment: @Maniero discordo, o lema da linguagem python é que tudo é um objeto. Talvez o que você afirmou seja verdade para algumas linguagens mas não para Python. Quando você interage com o objeto `s` está fazendo uma chamada ao método `replace` da classe str.

Comment: Já vi algumas pessoas afirmando isso, mas não vi um documento canônico com isso. Já blog de gente influente na comunidade falando isso e o resto repetindo como papagaio, o que não quer dizer que esteja correto. Eu ainda não li a resposta dada por inteiro porque preciso sair, mas o começo parece promissor, até porque o hkotsubo costuma responder as cosias adequadamente e não compra esses mitos que o pessoal espalha por aí. Fica o alerta para quem quer aprender certo. Qualquer linguagem que queira repelir um conceito da computação não merece crédito. Não estou afirmando que a linguagem faz isso.

Comment: Maniero, a variável s fazer referência a um objeto string. Tanto é assim, que podemos utilizar métodos acessando a variável, como em s.upper(). Então, eu não entendi a diferenciação de variável e objeto nesse caso.

Comment: Carlos, inicialmente a variável `s` aponta para um objeto (a string "banana"). Depois do `s = s.replace(...)`, a variável passa a apontar para outro objeto (a string "zanana"). Ou seja, a variável só aponta para um objeto, mas ela não é o objeto: veja na minha resposta que depois do `replace` a variável `s` aponta para "zanana", mas a string "banana" continua existindo - ou seja, temos uma variável (`s`) e dois objetos (as strings "banana" e "zanana"). A variável, no fim, é apenas um nome dado para referenciar um valor (leia os links que o Maniero indicou e que eu também coloquei na resposta)

Comment: O fato de poder chamar um método de um objeto através da variável não significa que a variável é o objeto. O que ocorre é que o método é chamado no objeto para o qual a variável aponta, mas ainda sim são coisas separadas. Por exemplo, `x = 'abc'`, a variável `x` aponta para a string "abc". Depois faço `x = 'z'`. A variável `x` mudou (agora aponta pra "z"), mas a string "abc" (o objeto para o qual `x` apontava antes) permanece inalterada. Se a variável fosse o próprio objeto (se `x` fosse a string "abc", em vez de apontar para ela), ao fazer `x = 'z'` a string "abc" também seria modificada

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Isso é uma alteração da string original ou não?*

**Não.**

Vamos acompanhar passo a passo (de forma simplificada) o que acontece:

```
s = "banana"
```

Aqui criamos um objeto do tipo string (para ser mais preciso, uma instância da classe `str`), cujo conteúdo é o texto "banana", e atribuímos na variável `s`. Ou seja, temos algo assim:

[image: s aponta para "banana"]

Depois, nesta linha:

```
s = s.replace("b", "z")
```

Aqui tem duas coisas acontecendo: primeiro `replace` **retorna outra string** (no caso, "zanana"), e depois o resultado é atribuído na variável `s`. Então agora está assim:

[image: s aponta para "zanana"]

Ou seja, a variável `s` agora aponta para a string "zanana". Mas a string "banana" continua lá, inalterada (ela só não tem mais ninguém apontando para ela, mas note que ela em si não foi modificada).

---

Uma forma de ver que a variável mudou (que ela aponta para outro objeto) é imprimir o `id` da mesma. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), no CPython (que provavelmente é a implementação que você está usando) é retornado o endereço do objeto na memória. Então podemos fazer esse teste:

```
s = "banana"
# imprime a string e o id
print(s, id(s)) # banana 19192864

s = s.replace("b", "z")
print(s, id(s)) # zanana 24317376
```

Os números exatos vão mudar cada vez que você executar e não serão os mesmos que coloquei acima. Mas o importante é que o `id` antes e depois do `replace` não serão os mesmos, porque depois do `replace` a variável `s` passa a apontar para a outra string que foi gerada, e não mais para a original.

Isso vale para todos os métodos de que "modificam" a string (como `upper`, `lower`, etc): na verdade eles retornam outra string com o valor modificado. Tanto que você pode fazer assim:

```
s = "banana"
# atribuir o resultado de replace para outra variável, em vez de "s"
outra = s.replace("b", "z")

print(s) # banana
print(outra) # zanana
```

Se uma string fosse mutável, o método `replace` mudaria o próprio valor de `s`, mas veja acima que não foi o caso. `s` continuou sendo "banana", e a variável `outra`, que recebe o retorno de `replace` é que passa a apontar para a nova string. O detalhe é que essa variável poderia ser o próprio `s` (como no seu código), mas isso não quer dizer que a string mudou, e sim que a variável passou a apontar para outra string. [Variável é uma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/112052), e [objeto é outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/112052).

Se uma string fosse mutável, o código abaixo não daria erro:

```
s = "banana"
# mudar o primeiro caractere da string (**dá erro!**)
s[0] = 'z' # TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

---

Apenas para fins de comparação, listas em Python são mutáveis, o que quer dizer que você pode modificá-las, sem precisar criar outra lista e nem atribuir a outra variável:

```
lista = [3, 20, 1]
print(id(lista))

# adiciona um elemento
lista.append(10)

# remove o primeiro
lista.pop(0)

# ordena
lista.sort()

print(lista) # [1, 10, 20]
print(id(lista)) # será o mesmo impresso no início
```

Eu imprimi o `id` da lista antes e depois das operações, e veja que ele será o mesmo, pois continua sendo a mesma lista: somente os elementos dela é que são alterados.

Repare que não preciso fazer algo como `lista = lista.sort()`, pois `sort` já ordena a própria lista (em vez de retornar outra lista ordenada). O mesmo não acontece com strings, então apenas chamar `replace` não é suficiente: você precisa pegar o valor retornado, pois a string original não é modificada. É isso que queremos dizer com "strings são imutáveis".

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação completa hkotsubo. Já que você citou a mudança de atribuição à variável s, quando você muda o valor de uma mesma variável, ocorre o mesmo que quando você usa um método numa string, ou seja, a variável permanece a mesma, mas os IDs ficam diferentes, pois apontam para valores diferentes? Por exemplo: em x = 10 print(id(x)) x = 20 print(id(x)) os IDs serão diferentes, pois apontam para objetos diferentes. Esse caso é o mesmo em relação à utilização de métodos como replace, upper ou lower?  É o que chamam de parte dinamicamente tipada do Python?

Comment: @CarlosSanches Quando você chama um método, ele é chamado no objeto para o qual a variável aponta. `s.replace` vai chamar o `replace` para a string que `s` está apontando. Não sei se foi isso que vc quis saber...

Comment: @CarlosSanches Já sobre "dinamicamente tipada", isso é outra coisa (quer dizer que as variáveis podem mudar o tipo, por exemplo, posso fazer `s = 'abc'` - `s` é uma string - e depois posso fazer `s = 1` - `s` é um número inteiro). Ou seja, a mesma variável pode assumir valores de tipos completamente diferentes. Sobre esse assunto, sugiro ler aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/112052

Comment: Ok. Obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 5):

De acordo com a documentação da classe [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

> Dados textuais em Python são tratados como objetos `str`, ou strings. Strings são sequências **imutáveis** de *code points* Unicode.

Então, como strings são imutáveis em Python, é de se esperar que métodos como o `replace` não alterem a string original, mas sim *criem* e retornem uma *nova* string.

No caso do `str.replace`, é possível referir à [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) para entender melhor o que está acontecendo:

> **`str.replace(old, new)`**
>
> Retorna uma *cópia* da string com todas as ocorrências da substring `old` substituídas por `new`.

E, de fato, conforme sugere um dos [comentários da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500210/se-strings-em-python-s%C3%A3o-imut%C3%A1veis-como-conseguimos-alter%C3%A1-la-com-o-m%C3%A9todo-repl#comment926150_500210), pode-se utilizar a função embutida [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) para confirmar que `replace` retorna um objeto diferente do original, uma vez que possuem endereços de memória<sup>[1]</sup> diferentes:

```
>>> s = "banana"
>>> id(s)
4441918384
>>> s = s.replace("b", "z")
>>> id(s)
4440837616 # ID diferente do anterior. Trata-se, portanto, de um novo valor!
```

---

Algumas linguagens permitem a modificação de strings, mas como esse não é o caso do Python, não é correto esperar que um método (ou qualquer outro código) seja capaz de modificar uma string, já que a própria linguagem determina que se trata de uma *estrutura de dados imutável*.

Então, no seu código,

> ```
> s = "banana"
> s = s.replace("b", "z")
>
> print(s) # zanana
> ```

Você não está modificando a string criada pela expressão literal `"banana"`. O `replace` está *criando* uma *nova* string que é, enfim, utilizada na **reatribuição** da variável `s`.

O que muda é a variável `s`, já que você está alterando o valor para qual ela aponta. Antes, apontava para `"banana"` e, após a *reatribuição*, aponta para `"zanana"`.

O código em questão cria **duas** strings diferentes, que jamais são ou serão modificadas.

Para mais detalhes, ler [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/69296).

---

<sup>[1]: O endereço de memória é o valor retornado por `id` na implementação CPython. A documentação garante, no entanto, que é uma identificação única para objetos diferentes.</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Luiz. De fato, olhar a documentação responde clara e rapidamente o meu questionamento. "Cópia" já diz tudo. A dúvida é gerada em quem está começando, como eu, por conta da variável ser a mesma. Mas os IDs diferentes já respondem a isso também.