# Python: Função 'upper' e 'lower' não funcionam

Tags: python, funções, visual-studio-code

Estou realizando experimentos em Python e dessa vez meus alvos foram as funções que tratam Strings.

Em meus testes, estou tentando fazer um conversor de textos, porém, as funções não estão realizando suas funcionalidades no meu Visual Studio Code. **O estranho é que no IDLE as conversões ocorrem normalmente, o problema ocorre apenas no VSCode.**

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Segue print.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: strings são objetos imutáveis. Veja essa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500210/se-strings-em-python-s%C3%A3o-imut%C3%A1veis-como-conseguimos-alter%C3%A1-la-com-o-m%C3%A9todo-repl

Comment: Apesar da pergunta indicada acima não ser 100% exatamente idêntica, a ideia é a mesma: qualquer método que "modifica" a string (como `lower`, `upper`, etc), na verdade retorna outra string, então vc precisa atribuir o retorno em alguma variável (inclusive uma das respostas menciona exatamente isso), e portanto a solução é a mesma (por isso indiquei como duplicada)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa atribuir a uma variável.

Seu código pode ficar assim:

```
name = 'Romulo'
name = name.upper()
print(name)
```

SAÍDA: ROMULO

Comment: O meu código se encontra exatamente do jeito que você citou em sua resposta, porém continua sem funcionar no VSCode. Lembrando que no IDLE, com o mesmo padrão, funcionou conforme esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você precise declarar uma nova variável passando o `name.upper()` nesta nova e depois imprimir ou então colocar a função `upper()` diretamente dentro do print para funcionar. O que esta acontecendo é que você esta usando o `upper()` e depois na linha de baixo onde imprime este não está mais sendo utilizado.

Comment: Poderia ser válido se também não tivesse funcionado no IDLE. Este mesmo código postado em minha pergunta funcionou perfeitamente no IDLE, apresentando erro apenas no VSCode.

Comment: **paco**, não use cumprimentos ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado pelos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)