# Como substituir caracteres por asterisco de um string em Python?

Tags: python

Preciso de um código que recebe uma string e troca todas as letras por asteriscos, execeto a primeira e a ultima de cada palavra. segue o exemplo:

Entrada

Rua Barão do Caí 125

Saída

```
>> R*a B***o do C*í 125
```

meu código esta assim, mas não funciona:

```
frase = 'Rua Barão do Caí 125'

lista = frase.split()

for palavra in lista:
    if len(palavra) <= 2:
        pass
    elif len(palavra) == 3:
        palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1], "*")
    elif len(palavra) == 4:
        palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1], "*")
    elif len(palavra) == 5:
        palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1], "*")
    elif len(palavra) == 6:
        palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1], "*")
    elif len(palavra) == 7:
        palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1], "*")
```

Comment: Os números não podem ser substituídos por asteríscos?

Comment: Relacionada: [Se strings em Python são imutáveis, como conseguimos alterá-la com o método replace()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/500210/69296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que, em Python, strings são imutáveis. Você não pode alterar caracteres individuais trocando-os por asteriscos, mas pode formar uma nova string com base em pedaços de outras.

Uma tentativa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

frase = 'Rua Barão do Caí 125'

lista = frase.split()

for i, palavra in enumerate(lista):
    try:
        numero = int(palavra)
        # é número
        continue
    except ValueError:
        # é palavra mesmo
        pass

    if len(palavra) >= 3:
        # ofusca
        palavra = palavra[0] + ("*" * (len(palavra) - 2)) + palavra[-1]
        lista[i] = palavra

print(" ".join(lista))
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução para seu problema:

```
frase = "Rua Barão do Caí 125"

lista = frase.split()
new_frase = []

for palavra in lista:
  numero = False
  try:
    int(palavra) # Verifica se é número
    numero = True
  except:
    pass
  if len(palavra) > 2 and not numero:
    palavra = palavra.replace(palavra[1:-1],"*"*(len(palavra)-2))
  new_frase.append(palavra)
new_frase = ' '.join(new_frase)
print(new_frase)
```

Resultado:

```
R*a B***o do C*í 125
```